# split object with matching keys in existing array

Tags: javascript

```
myArray   = ['1', '2', '3'];

myObj     = { 1-vehicle : 'car', 2-vehicle : 'bike', 3-vehicle : 'train' };

resultObj = {
    '1': { '1-vehicle': 'car' }, 
    '2': { '2-vehicle': 'bike' },
    '3': { '3-vehicle': 'train' }
};
```

I am having an object where each key is starting with a number and also I have and array with some values. I am trying to match those key and values and split up the object. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

I have tried it and i am posting my code below but I am not successful

```
{
    Object.keys(myObj).filter((key: any) => {
        for (const i in myArray) {
            if (myArray[i] === key.charAt(0)) {
                newObj[key] = myObj[key]
                resultObj[myArray[i]] = newObj
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Your final result has not correct format.

Comment: Thanks! I have edited the question

Comment: it is neither an array nor an object.

Comment: sorry my bad. changed to object

Comment: maybe a word is necessary. by taking changing keys, which requires more information like a given array or if you need to split the keys for getting adddtional information, you may better use an array with objects who have same key names and all other information is stored inside of the object with the same key, like an `id`.

Comment: Next time please click the `[<>]` and create a [mcve] - I realise there was ONE react thing left: `(key: any)`

Comment: `1-vehicle` is not a valid property name in the `myObj` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var res = {};
for(let k in myObj){
  if(k[0])res[k[0]]= {[k]:myObj[k]};
}
```

the simplest and shortest solution is

Answer (score 3):

You could map the wanted parts and assign objects to a single object.

This solution feature a closure over the combined key of the object.

```js
var array = ['1' , '2' , '3'],
    object = { '1-vehicle': 'car', '2-vehicle': 'bike', '3-vehicle': 'train' },
    result = Object.assign(
        ...array.map(v => (k => ({ [v]: { [k]: object[k] } }))(v + '-vehicle'))
    );

console.log(result);
```